# Adding a JLabel under a JPanel not working (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing

I'm designing a long and signup page as a test for some java projects and whilst trying to append the JLabel under the existing panel, the text does not show up.

Here is the code:

```
//Setting Panel Color
int r1 = 172;
int g1 = 50;
int b1 = 50;
Color myFgColor = new Color(r1,g1,b1);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(750,60,375,420);
panel.setBackground(myFgColor);
        
//Login and Sign Up Text
JLabel label = new JLabel("LOGIN");
label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
label.setForeground(Color.white);
panel.add(label);
gui.getContentPane().add(panel);
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for a basic example. Download the `FrameDemo`. Just change the code to actual add text to the label. Don't attempt to use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers and the layout manager will set the size/location of the label.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Are you trying to add more than one component to the content pane, perchance?

Comment: @VGR https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/039c78ce95364a55b53ada4b88c39b76 here is the full code, it might help you a bit more but the only other thing I'm adding to the content pane is the background

Comment: @NathanTolley, Post code in the forum. Actually a better code example is the `LabelDemo` from [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LabelDemoProject/src/components/LabelDemo.java). It is better structured and shows how to add a child panel containing your components to the frame. The main() method should only create the frame and then add the child panel to the frame. The order of code execution is important. Components need to be added to the frame before the frame is visible.

Comment: [The documentation for JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html) says “The default content pane will have a BorderLayout manager set on it.” [The documentation for BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) says “Each region may contain no more than one component” and says “BorderLayout interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant CENTER.” In other words, you can only add one thing to the content pane’s main area.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to see?

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oODbe.png)

I didn't change anything, I just created a new JFrame and put your components...
The difference I see is that JFrame creates the contentPane, and you didn't:

```
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window frame = new Window();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Window() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(1200, 575);
    setResizable(false);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);    

    //Setting Panel Color
    Color myFgColor = new Color(172,50,50);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(750,60,375,420);
    panel.setBackground(myFgColor);
            
    //Login and Sign Up Text
    JLabel label = new JLabel("LOGIN");
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    label.setForeground(Color.white);
    panel.add(label);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    //Setting Background Color
    Color myBgColor = new Color(30,30,30);
    getContentPane().setBackground(myBgColor);
    
    //Centering Window
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

I recommend you using WindowBuilder to create frames, it's a visual designer and it makes it very easy